# How to make a MDM App and upload it to app store?

Tags: ios, mdm

We have made some questions to different departments in Apple´s developers support web, but answers was made by non-developers personal.

The technical questions that we asked still unanswered, and we was referenced to documentation which we already have read. We need to solve some issues, which we have not be able to resolve either with the official documentation or by searching in forums (inside and outside to Apple).

We are a company that has developed an app for android platforms and we are currently checking the viability to make an IOS version. But we are found a lot of limitations when we have tried to develop some functionalities. Due to confidentiality reasons I can´t explain too much details but the app requires certain tasks such as blocking devices.

The only way we have found to be able to do something like this is through the application of MDM. Currently we have an "Apple developer program" account, which according to the documentation is intended to publish apps in the app store, but we have seen that in order to use MDM an "Apple developer enterprise program" account is required, which according to the documentation it´s designed for the distribution of internal app for the management of devices within a company.

The first and most important question: What we intend to do is an application for the app store that uses MDM, since there is no other way to get the necessary permissions on the device to perform some kind of tasks (like block device, for example). I mean, we want to develop an app that would be a hybrid between the two types of development plans. Is this possible if we enroll in the "Apple developer enterprise program"?

We have found some similar questions in the forum, but have no answer:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/262622#262622

If it´s possible. How? Developing with an enterprise account, but upload it to the app store with a normal developer account or how? Or is this kind of app a special case and it´s allowed to upload it to the app store although it was implemented with a enterprise developer account? Or is there some way that we have not seen in the documentation to apply MDM in an app developed with the normal developers plan?

These are speculations, but are some of the possibilities that we see that we would have, because if we are strict relative to documentation contents, 
it seems that with the  "Apple developer enterprise program" can´t publish apps in app store, and with "Apple developer program" MDM can´t be applied.

Moreover, documentation focuses too much on "what" can be done with MDM, but does not clarify enough “how" do it.  We haven´t seen any published examples, 
or a step-by-step tutorial to make a MDM server from scratch, and unofficial documentation and examples ones on this topic are scarce, or practically non-existent.

We've seen that there are apps in the app store that apply MDM, that's why it makes us think that it's possible, but if you're strict with what documentation says, it seems that each type of account has different purposes. And we wouldn't like to invest time and resources in a development of an app that finally will be rejected at the time of the review prior to its publication in the app store.

Some examples of apps that we found in the app store that apply MDM are the following:

- Flipd: https://itunes.apple.com/es/app/flipd-keep-focused/id1071708905?mt=8
- Qustodio – Parental control: https://itunes.apple.com/es/app/qustodio-control-parental/id990229433?mt=8

If finally it is possible to do it, another limitation that we have founded is that only one MDM configuration profile can be installed per device. This means that if the user already has one in his terminal, the installation of the configuration profile of our app (required for its correct functionality) would fail.

In no case can be installed more files of this type? If not, would it be permissible to ask the user, as a prerequisite in the installation of the app, 
to uninstall the other MDM configuration file of his/her device? If in any case several profiles are allowed, we can not think of another way to guarantee that the app works correctly.

In order to apply some restrictions to the devices (execute MDM lock payload for example) we need to activate the "supervised mode". We have seen that with 
the Apple Configurator 2 application it can be  done, but to do that it is needed to connect the device to a computer physically. Can "supervised mode" be activated remotely and programmatically? How?

Also, we have read that there is no problem in activating this mode in new devices, but if the device has already been used it is necessary to format it to active “supervised mode”. Is this essential or mandatory?  Of course, we can´t ask users to format their device to install our app. If it would be mandatory to format the device in order to activate “supervised mode”, Is there any other way to block the device programmatically without this mode?

Answer (score 2):

An MDM server communicates with a managed device using push notifications.  In order to send these push notifications an MDM deployment needs a certificate that has been signed by the MDM vendor.  In order to sign these certificates, the MDM vendor needs a certificate from Apple that is only available through the enterprise app development program.

In your case you would be both the MDM vendor and the MDM user, but you still need the enterprise program membership in order to create the required certificate.

You would use your regular developer program membership to create an App Store app that interacts with your MDM server.

The MDM protocol is [comprehensively documented by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/enterprise/documentation/MDM-Protocol-Reference.pdf) - See Chapter 9 for a description of the MDM signing process.

Creating an MDM server from scratch is a non-trivial exercise and so it is unlikely that you will find a step-by-step tutorial; The sort of companies that are capable of implementing an MDM don't need it and an organisation that does need one probably isn't capable of doing it.

You are correct that only one device management profile can be installed at a time. The most common situation where a management profile already exists is where the device is being managed by an enterprise.  In this case it is unlikely that the user would remove this management profile as it is probably a condition of using their device with their enterprise data.

If the controls you want to implement require a supervised device then you either need to connect the device to a Mac and use the Apple Configurator or the device must be linked to an organisation via the Device Enrolment Program (DEP), which allows Over-the-air supervision.  An organisation that is using DEP will be directing their devices to their own MDM and they won't want to use yours instead.

Supervision using Apple Configurator requires that the device is either brand new or has been completely erased.